# C# - WPF: Looping through PDF Files and display in browser control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a file watcher service, and I want to display each time a PDF is placed in the folder. I am able to view the first file, but the next one  I add shows "Page cannot be displayed". It is not looping to the next file. Please can you advice

```
Public void FileSystemWatcher_Created(Object Sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = e.FullPath;
    Action action = () =>
    {
      pdfwindow.WbPdf.Navigate(filepath);
    };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the FileSystemWatcher is so fast there are file read write conflicts. Put a small delay before trying to Navigate to see if that will help.

```
Public void FileSystemWatcher_Created(Object Sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = e.FullPath;
    Action action = async () =>
    {
       await Task.Delay(10);
      pdfwindow.WbPdf.Navigate(filepath);
    };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Clayton, that worked for me. I had to increase the delay by 20 and it worked superb. Thank you so much